# Django set_password not working

Tags: django, django-authentication, change-password

I set the user password and it checks out, but I can't login in various login forms. I can't authenticate:

```
u = User.objects.get(username='foobar')
u.set_password('123')
u.save()
u.check_password('123')  # True
authenticate(username='foobar', password='123')  # None?!?!
```

I can't log the user in though I've tried various ways.

Comment: are you using the default `User` model?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the user `is_active`. If the user does not have the `.is_active` flag set to `True`, it can lead to unusual behavior. Maybe your user got accidentally shadow banned :D